# Why doesn't the output change?

Tags: python, list, reference, concatenation

I'm studying for a Python final on Wednesday.
I'm having some issues with the references in lists.
I need some explanation as to what is happening.

I've tried googling/searching through my teacher's notes to no avail

If I have the following python code:

Part A)

```
a = [1,2]
b = [1,[2], 3]
c = [a] + [b]
b = 0
print(c)
```

Yet if I say:

Part B)

```
a = [1,2]
b = [1,[2], 3]
c = [a] + [b]
b[0] = -1
print(c)
```

Part A)
Output for c = [[1, 2], [1, 2, [3]]]

Why doesn't c print out as [ [1,2], [0]]?

Part B)
output of c would be = [[1, 2], [-1, [2], 3]]

It seems to modify the reference to b inside of the object c in this case, but not the other case.

I have to draw an arrow diagram for this, so it's all really confusing as to what's happening with the references and why if I change b by the index it seems to change b inside of c, but if I change what b is referring to, c is referring to the old value of b still and not the new value of b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c = [a] + [b]` will use the values of variable `a` and variable `b`, both of which are lists. `b = 0` changes the contents of `b`, making it forget about the previous value it held (which remains unchanged, it is merely not referenced by `b` any more). `b[0] = -1` doesn't change `b`, it changes the value `b` references; since that value is also referenced by the list currently in `c`, you will observe the change in `c`.

The best advice I have is to run both pieces of code through the very effective Python Visualizer tool: [snippet 1](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B1,2%5D%0Ab%20%3D%20%5B1,%5B2%5D,%203%5D%0Ac%20%3D%20%5Ba%5D%20%2B%20%5Bb%5D%0Ab%20%3D%200%0Aprint%28c%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) vs [snippet 2](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%5B1,2%5D%0Ab%20%3D%20%5B1,%5B2%5D,%203%5D%0Ac%20%3D%20%5Ba%5D%20%2B%20%5Bb%5D%0Ab%5B0%5D%20%3D%20-1%0Aprint%28c%29&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false), and observe how the program runs (press the "Visualize Execution" button).

Comment: The visualization part was really good to understand this. Didn't know about that website. Thanks.

Comment: I think my confusion was that I was thinking about this like they're pointers and confusing it with references. 
I have a background of C++ but I'm pretty bad at pointers/references. I kept thinking they're frikkin pointers.

Thanks!

Comment: They basically _are_ pointers, you just never see them as such (i.e. you can't do pointer arithmetics or things like that). You would get exactly the same result in C++ for this code. The critical thing is that "variable" does not equal "variable's content". The first snippet changes the _variable_, but not the content it used to have. The second snippet changes the _variable's content_, though the variable remains unchanged (still has the same reference/pointer).